# Visualize high resolution data

Tags: geospatial, data-visualization, data-warehouse

I'm searching a way to STORE (exploiting SQLServer2008) and VISUALIZE a High Resolution data coming from manufacturing process.

Those data are related to the surface of wood strip. In detail I have data collected in a High Frequency (250 process parameters measured 3500 times for each wood strip) related to the process parameters and surface defects of wood strip.

That I want is to answare a query like the following:
 - Retrieve all available HR data within a certain wood-region over one whole production period containing thousands of wood strip.
OR BETTER
- Retrieve all high resolution data within a certain region of the wood strip (defined by X,Y coordinate) on a production period containing a very large amount of worked wood strip.

I know the potentially of DW solution, but I don't know if the classical DW is useful to deal with this kind of problem, or the exploitation of some spatial assumption on that, i.e. the X coordinate of each measurement.

Thanks,

Nko

Comment: Storing the data seems straightforward, but querying it may not be, especially if the regions are irregular shapes (I'm not sure why you tagged this geospatial, by the way?). If you want suggestions on efficient querying then you might need to clarify that point.

Comment: Thanks Pondlife. I want to perform query like the following: - Get the avg value of process parameters (or defects) related to strips  aggregated on date hierarchy (by week, month, quarter, year) within a certain region of the coil, further with the possibility to drill-down in order to see the values related to each single strip

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
create table strips (strip_id int primary key, [other strip parameters]);

create table parameters (parameter_id int primary key, parameter_description varchar(200));

create table strip_hr_data (strip_id int, parameter_id int, x int, y int, value whatever(), primary key(strip_id,parameter_id,x,y));
```

This way you can have an arbitrary number of parameters and an arbitrary number of samples by strip.

To visualize your data you

```
select strip_id, parameter_dscription ,x,y, value 
from strips a 
inner join strip_hr_data b on (a.strip_id = b.strip_id)
inner join parameters c on (b.parameter_id = c.parameter_id)
where (whatever filters you want...)
```

and either C&P the data or ODBC it to excel an make a pivot table.
You wil get a table with all your selected trips, with parameter values for each location

Tanking it a step forward, you could create dimensions for every parameter and aggregate data, creating a true DW and not just a repository.

cheers

Comment: Thank you very much. But I have a question: the table strip_hr_data becomes too large considering that for each process parameter thare are about 3500 measurement for each strip? Will I have performance problem in the analisys stage?

Comment: Like I said, this is a repository... Given the volume of data that you want to store, you will always have an astronomical number of records. In a loss-less context, the most you can do is build a table with 250+ attributes (one for each measurement plus keys) but you loose the dynamic nature of the DB, you will be stuck with your current measurements and, depending on your data capture, your ETL might become harder to understand. What you could do is aggregate data... You could average out regions of your strips. Suppose you average every 4 positions, you would reduce you data 4 fold.

Comment: The goal of the solution that I will develop is the visualization of the paramters and defects not aggregated in the same strip. What about a DW solution considering as FACT as the strip and as DIMENSIONS each "process paramters" (id, posX, posY, value) and "defects" (id, posX, posY, value). Cheers Nko

Comment: Same thing. You would have a Fact table with 250+ FKs and each dimension would hold every possible/previous value for every strip. Without aggregation you will always have trouble with the huge amount of data. The best you can do is index everything properly and setup the repository on a decent machine. Cheers